# Customization of Search in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

> I need to customize "Search" for my website.
>   The requirement is to search only posts by "Category" "Author" "Date-time" and two "custom-fields". 
>   Or is there any plugin which can I use for this task.

Comment: Google `Customization of Search in wordpress`

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-custom-fields-search/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-custom-fields-search/

OR work in the search.php file then here update queries with http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts or http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Good luck! :)

Comment: @Henrich: Thanks for the help, I have got what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called *WP Custom Search*. I used this plugin to search by user, category (using own ajax script). Also you can search by custom fields.